# Type of relational/object-oriented database with improved joins for object graphs?

Tags: join, relational-theory, orm, graph, dbms

I would like to know if there is a specific name or term for the kind of database described below:

I notice one of the biggest problems when working with relational databases and object trees/graphs is fetching of sub-/child-/grandchild rows(objects in code), especially over many hierarchy levels.

Doing this by join results in a kind of cartesian product between result rows. Example with only two top level table rows and three levels in hierarchy:

```
SELECT p.[columns], c.[columns], gc.[columns]
FROM Parents p
LEFT JOIN Children c ON p.ID=c.ParentID
LEFT JOIN Grandchildren gc ON c.ID=gc.ParentID
WHERE p.Name in ('A','B')

-- result:

Parent A | Child AA | Grandchild AAA
Parent A | Child AA | Grandchild AAB
Parent A | Child AA | Grandchild AAC
Parent A | Child AB | Grandchild ABA
Parent A | Child AB | Grandchild ABB
Parent A | Child AC | Grandchild ACA
Parent A | Child AC | Grandchild ACB
Parent B | Child BA | Grandchild BAA
Parent B | Child BA | Grandchild BAB
Parent B | Child BB | Grandchild BBA
Parent B | Child BB | Grandchild BBB
```

So, even a few results with all sub-elements quickly make hundreds or thousands of rows, and if the parent table has tons of heavy NCLOB/BLOB/NVARCHAR(MAX) columns, there's a HUGE amount of data to be transmitted as duplicates.

Some object-relational mappers work around this by SELECTing child and grandchild rows by their parents' IDs (the good ones loading them in groups/batches, not single SELECTs for each parent row!), but this is likely not transactional (subordinate/child rows may have been changed after parent rows were selected, not possible in a join - and of course you don't want to do this in "serializable" isolation level).

A possible solution would be to transmit join results in a different format: instead of duplicating parent rows, they would transmit them only once, plus a reference between them and subordinate rows (likely the original PK/FK). In the most simple case, multiple result sets from all joined tables would be transmitted, with each row (or row projection) only once, to be easily transformed into objects by the client application:

```
Parent A | Child AA | Grandchild AAA
                    | Grandchild AAB
                    | Grandchild AAC
         | Child AB | Grandchild ABA
                    | Grandchild ABB
         | Child AC | Grandchild ACA
                    | Grandchild ACB
Parent B | Child BA | Grandchild BAA
                    | Grandchild BAB
         | Child BB | Grandchild BBA
                    | Grandchild BBB
```

only 2 parent table rows and 5 child table rows. The whole thing as transactional as a classic join. If somebody wants a classic join result (for example, when using classic relational in-memory structures like ADO.NET DataSets), the person can easily transform it from the multi-table or "jagged" to the traditional, bloated "rectangular" join result.

The data backend could still be relational and have tables, but object graphs and joins would be much better to handle.

There have been multiple buzzwords around in the recent decades, including object databases, XML databases, graph databases, some of which claim to keep full relational integrity and ACID between all elements (I do not mean document only or non-/partially ACID databases in the NoSQL area - I mean with full ACID, also indices transactional, OLTP usable, but possibly limited scalability).

Also, the DB should not be too close to specific programming languages, but basically provide sets of common data types, which can be loaded into or extracted from language specific data structures.

The abovementioned database types may fit my definition, but in my idea, there should be a schema and table-like structures which allow both retrieval of object graphs and large numbers of rows and related rows by conditions. I am not sure whether object or graph databases are internally heap or table (relational) organized.

Can anybody name me the DBMS type which fits my definition, possibly name products?

Comment: A database that supports Recursive Common Table Expressions is a good start. Read Joe Celko's Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties, and Ch 27 of Joe Celko's SQL for Smarties (5th)